# Select only values from one column in a table in SQL with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to get only the countrys who just played in the pre round

```
Country   Round
Germany   Pre Round
Germany   Quater final
Spain     Pre Round
Portugal  Pre Round
```

And I just want to get the countrys which only played in the pre round. So the result should look like this:

```
Country
Spain
Portugal
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `group by country` and set the conditions in the having clause:

```
select country
from tablename
group by country
having count(*) = 1 and max(round) = 'Pre Round'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below using `not exists`

```
select country from c
where not exists 
(select 1 from c as c1 where c.country=c1.country and roundval<>'Pre Round')
```

Answer (score 0):

Two more for fun. The first is kind of a variation on @forpas', assigning a numeric value to each round, representing the progression through the rounds, and then getting the highest for the country (which would be simpler if the rounds were stored separately with a round number):

```
select country
from your_table
group by country
having max(case round
    when 'Pre Round' then 1
    when 'Quater final' then 2
    when 'Semi final' then 3
    when 'Final' then 4
  end) = 1;
```

If you wanted to find countries that were in the quarters but not semis then you just need to change to `= 2`, etc.

The second is overkill here, but could be useful to look for more complicated combinations in other types of data:

```
select country
from your_table
pivot (
  count(*) for round in (
    'Pre Round' as pre, 'Quater final' as quarter, 'Semi final' as semi, 'Final' as final
  )
)
where pre = 1 and quarter = 0 and semi = 0 and final = 0;
```

Obviously in your example you wouldn't ever have quarter as 0 and then either semi or final as 1 - you can't get to those rounds without playing the quarters; but for other data you might want a mix.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a inner join on subquery for country wih round 're Round' and check for distinct count

```
select m.Contry
from my_table  m
inner join  (
    select  Country
    from my_table  
    where round ='Pre Round'
) t  on t.country  = m.country
group by  m.Country
having count(distinct m.round ) = 1
```